# error while trying to insert new event to the calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I'm trying to add a new event to the calendar (min sdk version is 2.2).
That is the code i have so far:

```
ContentValues event = new ContentValues();

event.put("calendar_id", 2);
event.put("title", "mytitle");
event.put("description", "desc");
event.put("eventLocation", "loc");
event.put("eventTimezone", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getDisplayName());

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60;
Long duration = 1000L * 60 * 30;

event.put("dtstart", startTime);
event.put("duration", duration);

Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
Uri insertedUri = getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
```

But the `insertedUri` is always null.
Also i can see that line in my logcat:

```
Failed to find provider info for calendar
```

Can anyone help me with that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in [here](http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2010/08/09/add-events-on-google-calendar-on-android-froyo/).
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** default calendar in Android. So, it always fails to find the provider.That is why there were no public APIs earlier. You will have to install a calendar application for ex, google calendar. For other thired party apps, go through their apis.

Comment: but i have it on my device. why i still can't add anything?

Comment: its better to use https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/ APIs for you work if you have google calendar

Comment: is there something i can do to add events if the device is offline?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this,

```
public static void addToCalendar(Context ctx, final String title,
            final long dtstart, final long dtend, final String location) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        intent.putExtra("beginTime", dtstart);
        intent.putExtra("allDay", false);
        intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
        intent.putExtra("endTime", dtend);
        intent.putExtra("title", title);
        intent.putExtra("eventLocation", location);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }
```